# Are there any silenced energy weapons availiable?

Tags: fallout-4

I've become a little over-reliant on the suppressors on my trusty 10mm and .50 cal guns. I'd like to start using some of the very nice legendary laser and plasma weapons I have, but unfortunately, it looks like there's no way to get a suppressor for either. Are there any silent energy weapons? Or energy weapons that can be made silent with a little elbow grease at a workbench?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, no.

There are only 9 energy weapons in the game (No, the Gauss Rifle uses magnets to fling tiny metal pellets at ludicrous speeds, and therefore doesn't count)

1. Laser gun
2. Plasma gun
3. Laser musket
4. Alien blaster
5. Flames
6. Gatling laser
7. Gamma gun
8. Institute gun
9. Cryolater

None of these have the option of affixing silencers, though there are anecdotal claims that laser guns are quieter than non-silenced weapons. I don't personally think those claims hold any water, but they exist.

Comment: Arguably also the gatling laser and cryolator. But your point stands.

Comment: Your argument on why the gauss rifle is not an energy weapon is valid, but it appears to be author logic. Can you confirm the game does not actually treat it as an energy weapon?

Comment: The gauss rifle was an energy weapon in previous games. The distinction is less important now. I'm not sure it actually matters anywhere, as opposed to previous games where you would take "Energy Weapons" perks. My experience in New Vegas tells me that laser rifles are much quieter than small guns, but I don't know if that would translate to this one. The laser rifle actually makes a loud noise when you fire it now.

Comment: @Timelord64 it deals physical damage, not energy damage

Comment: Gamma guns are only terrible when _you_ use them.  When enemies have them, the stagger/knockback effect makes them very effective.  Or if you have a Hazmat suit, entirely ineffective but still very annoying.  Also, although you can't silence a laser rifle, I've noticed that enemies are significantly less responsive to it than they are to non-silenced ballistic weapons.  So it's already _relatively_ stealthy.  And lastly...you also forgot to list the Institute rifle.

Comment: Actually in FO1 and FO2 the Gauss weapons (Pistol and Rifle) falls under the Small Guns category.  [Wiki article](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gauss_rifle_(Fallout_2))

Comment: @aroth An Institute laser rifle is still a laser rifle, not a different type of energy gun.  There's BoS combat armor (and BoS power armor, and other faction gear) in the game too, but that doesn't make for a whole new class of armor, just because a faction slapped its logo (and possibly a mod or two) on someting.

Comment: @HopelessN00b institute weapons are absolutely distinct weapons. You can't slap laser mods on an institute weapon and vice versa. The base institute has different stats from the base laser.

Comment: @Dallium Even so, it's still a type of laser gun, that does laser energy damage.  Even though it is a distinct, separate sub type of laser gun from the base laser gun, it is still a laser gun (albiet a crappier laser gun which doesn't use interchangeable mods).

Comment: @HopelessN00b that's like saying the double barreled shotgun is the same as the assault shotgun, because even though they have different stats, models and mods, they both fire shotgun shells. Anyway, these comments are getting too chatty.

Comment: @Dallium Double barreled shotguns and assault shotguns are the same ***type*** of weapon. They are both shotguns. They use shotgun shell ammunition, and deal ballistic damage.  Also, like the difference between institute laser guns and normal laser guns, one of the two is much inferior to the other... but that doesn't change what ***type*** of weapon it is.  Note the emphasized words.  Before you came along, we were all talking about weapon ***types***, and not trying to split hairs over the differences between specific models of the same weapon ***type***.

Comment: Technically you can find the plasma legendary mod on a ballistic gun for it to deal energy damage.

Comment: @z' You can (and there other mods and effects and unique weapons that add a different damage type), but that doesn't change the weapon type.  It's still a ballistic gun with added energy (or whatever) damage.  My favorite would be the [Spray n' Pray](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Spray_n'_Pray).  BOOM!

Comment: @HopelessN00b - Then why not just call every weapon a "gun", and say that there's only one type of weapon?  Or two, since melee weapons aren't guns.  The question, however, is about individual weapons, and the answer enumerates the different energy weapons available.  So for practical purposes, here, the institute weapons are separate.  And the in-game handling is different enough (institute rifle has a better rate of fire and improved accuracy over the laser rifle) that I'd argue that it is a different _type_ of weapon.  But that's not relevant to the question.